# Charles: Export only the request body as a seperate JSON file

Tags: charles-proxy

I use charles proxy tool to monitor the requests and response.

Although I can use the export feature of charles proxy tool to extract the complete file as a .chls file. As shown in the below picture,

[image]

That .chls file will have the URL, request headers, request body, response header, response body and many other details.

But what I need is only the **request body** to be saved as a **.json file**. Is there anyway that I can automate this process?

Answer (score 5):

Go to Charles > Proxy Tab > Enable the Web Interface:

[image]

After completing charles session you can launch http://control.charles/session/export-json url to get the JSON format of the request.

To automate this you can use curl command:

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("curl  -o file.json http://control.charles/session/export-csv");

Comment: what is this url ? I am using Charles native app not some web services ?

Comment: Navigate to Charles Proxy tool, Go to Proxy Tab, here you may find enable web interface section, check the radio button for enabling the web interface, now open the browser and go to http://control.charles/session/export-json

Answer (score 2):

In Charles v4.2.8, this is pretty easy. Just right click the recorded HTTP request, and click "Save Request...".

[image]

If HTTP request `Content-Type` is `application/json`, its body would be saved. Save the file as xxx.json and it's done.

Note: this feature is possibly added earlier than v4.2.8, but I'm not able to find any announcement in Charles' [version history](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/version-history/).